# Class input-group doesn't show placeholder or accept input in Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The following code works perfectly in Chrome, however it's broken in Firefox and IE. In these browsers it will not display the placeholder, nor will it allow the user to type in the input.

If you remove the `input-group` class, it will destroy the formatting, however it will fix both of these issues.

How can I fix this problem? Here's my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" />
    </div>                    
</div>
```

Comment: I updated a codepen with that HTML and bootstrap.min from bootstraps website and it works fine in chrome / firefox -- there must be something else going on that you've added. http://codepen.io/MathiasaurusRex/pen/mJVMgb?editors=110

Comment: Yeah, I found the issue. I've added padding to the input which has messed it up. Do you know what I can do as a replacement for the padding?

Comment: what visual effect are you trying to accomplish with the padding

Comment: Don't worry, I fixed it by adding a `height` attribute in the CSS